# How to make element hide if not having any string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a error email message in Paragraph tag but when there is no text i want to hide the paragraph tag.

This is html

```
 <p class="errorpara" id="errorpara">
<%= correct%> 
</p>
```

This is javascript code

```
var message = $(".errorpara").text();
              var txtLength = message.length;
                if(txtLength < 2 )
                {
                   document.getElementById("errorpara").display = "none";
                }
```

Comment: Your HTML isn't pain HTML it looks like it will be pre-processed by ERB. In that case, why do you need JavaScript at all? When you could simply surround the `p` element with `<% if correct && !correct.empty? %>`

Answer (score 0):

use style.display

```
var message = $("#errorpara").text(); 
var txtLength = message.length; if(txtLength < 2 ) { 
document.getElementById("errorpara").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: it has same name of class and id

Comment: found pronlem, you must use style.display

Comment: Or simply save the element first instead of retrieving it two times in two different ways. `var $errorpara = $("#errorpara")`, then `if ($errorpara.text().length < 2) $errorpara.css("display", "none")`